# How can i display image preview in HTML file field

Tags: javascript, html

I remember a template some time ago(don't remember the name) where the user could select a photo from his computer and the photo's thumbnail would be displayed in the form.  There was like this selct photobutton, when the user selected it, a small thumbnail would appear. I don't remember how that was done and haven't been able to find anything like it on the Internet either.

Does anybody know how it can be implemented(js/css)

Comment: Probably this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069421/in-html5-how-to-show-preview-of-image-before-upload

Comment: If you saw it a while before HTML5 came about, there were a couple of Flash implementations that used Flash and JavaScript (the user would select the file using a standard HTML File Browser and the preview would be loaded in using Flash), but I wouldn't recommend going down the Flash route unless you absolutely had to