# Uploadify show image before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I create template for the system that have a image.
I want that i will show the image the client uploading before it will upload to the server.
Here the template that i do:

```
<div id="${fileID}" class="uploadify-queue-item">
<div class="cancel">
    <a href="#">cancel upload</a>
</div>
<div class="uploadify-names">
    <span class="fileName">asdasdsd sadsas adsadsasafafs affasfafasfsfaasdasdsa</span>
    <span class="data"></span>
</div>
<div class="uploadify-progress">
    <div class="uploadify-progress-bar"><!--Progress Bar--></div>
</div>
<img class="img" src="image here" width="100" height="75" />
```

Im also use in multiple and the free version.

Comment: Perhaps this thread can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619076/preview-images-before-it-is-uploaded-for-more-than-one-image

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't really understand what is "canvas element" and how to use to help my problem.

Comment: Here is an example on how to add image to a canvas element: http://jsfiddle.net/influenztial/qy7h5/

Comment: Thanks but when I using "onDialogClose" and select the file that not working.. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'swf'             : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'        : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
            alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was successfully uploaded with a response of ' + response + ':' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

[Documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/)