# hidden Input type='file' is not triggering when its parent div has been clicked

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, jquery-click-event

Sorry if you find this question repetitive, but I looked around, tried, failed, so need your help.

**one.html**

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="one.css" >
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="one.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class='some-class' id="add-image">
            <input type="file" id="myfile" style="display:none" />
            <h4> I want to open the file upload dilogue when anywhere of this div has been clicked</h4>
       </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**one.css**

```
.some-class{
border: 1px solid grey;
}

h4{
    text-align:center;
}
```

**one.js**

```
$("#add-image").click(function(){
  $("input[id='myfile']").click();
});
```

It shows sometimes

***event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.***

sometimes

***uncaught rangeerror maximum call stack size exceeded***

**I don't know whats happening, if its a issue with the jquery version?
Can you please help me? A working code sample or maybe a jsfiddle?
Thank you in advance :)**

Comment: Have you tried `$('#myfile').click();` or `$('#myfile').focus();`?

Comment: tried both. Not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your html to

```
     <div class='some-class' id="add-image">
        <h4> I want to open the file upload dilogue when anywhere of this div has been clicked</h4>
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="myfile" style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the click handler within a dom ready handler because when `one.js` is executed the `add-image` element is not present in the dom structure

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#add-image").click(function () {
        $("#myfile").click();
    });
})
```

[Dom Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Since the file input element is within the `myfile` element triggering the click element on the file element will cause a recursive error saying [callstack exceeded](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9d2X4/1/)

The solution is to move the file element out of the `myfile` element

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" style="display:none" />
<div class='some-class' id="add-image">
     <h4> I want to open the file upload dilogue when anywhere of this div has been clicked</h4>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9d2X4/)

Comment: **Not working Arun. Throwing error like this:**

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.


Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: `event.returnValue is deprecated` is a warning in new versions of browsers... hopefully jQuery will handle it in the new versions

Comment: can you give some more info about the call stack issue

Comment: Means? I just put the error warning from the console. There's nothing more.

Comment: I know. but the file upload dilogue is not opening.

Comment: got the problem with callstack, you need to make a minor change in the markup

Comment: And Arun, can I ask one more thing please? Is there any way I can show that image on this div after selecting from the upload dialog?
Actually I'm new in Jquery want to learn more :)

Comment: you can look at the html5 file API

Comment: search for html5 image preview like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069421/in-html5-how-to-show-preview-of-image-before-upload

Answer (score 1):

I thin kyou have missed the dom ready handler. 
try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add-image").click(function(){
     $("#myfile").trigger('click');
  });
});
```

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded