# Get thumbnail from input type="file"

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building an photo *uploader*. When user choose a photo from `<input type="file">`

I use *jquery* to submit the selected file from user to my server, the server save that image to disk and make a thumbnail.

The server return the URL of the thumbnail to client.

Then *jquery* display the image to user.  That is client/server.

Now, can I show the thumbnail of selected file from user without post it to Server ?

( It's like Facebook photo *uploader*, we needn't click Preview to view thumbnail of selected Photo. Facebook do it for us )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), see demo from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069481/2021523):

```
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
    document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
};
```

Comment: 1. This should be a comment. 2. This question should be marked as duplicate. You shouldn't copy answers.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can only modern browsers support it.
You are looking for [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Take a look on this [quick tutorial](http://webomnizz.com/blog/jquery/ajax-upload-with-progress-bar-in-jquery/) that also includes the demo( Implemented FileReader API ) and progress bar as well.