# display image using javascript using the file upload

Tags: javascript

How to get image instead of image name in html using file input type. I have used the css file for positioning the image file. I have tried all the sorts of code given... Please help.

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" onchange="readURL()"/>


function readURL()
{
   document.getElementById('previewimage').style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In HTML5 how to show preview of image before upload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069421/in-html5-how-to-show-preview-of-image-before-upload)

Answer (score 1):

```
function readURL()
{
if (document.getElementById('photo').files && document.getElementById('photo').files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('previewimage').src = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('photo').files[0]);
}
}
function openFiledialog(){  
  document.getElementById('photo').click();
}
```

//

```
<input type='button' onclick='openFiledialog()' value='photo'/>
<input type="file" style='display:none;' name="photo" id="photo" onchange="readURL()"/>
```

Comment: try uploading smaller images

Comment: oh.. how to make the name of the image to disappear. Is that default while using input type file?

Comment: use this update code, only buton will be visible to the user.