# jQuery input file type handling

Tags: jquery, image, file, input, upload

How to make when select some image file using input file type then it upload and show on screen.

html:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="imagefile">
<div id="imageshow"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#imagefile").on("change",(function() {
//code of upload image
    //code of move image file from temp to /upload folder
    //code of show to div imageshow
}));
```

Should i use post get? or something else.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069421/in-html5-how-to-show-preview-of-image-before-upload

Comment: http://tomasdostal.com/projects/html5ImagePreview/

Comment: view the image before uploading or after uploading?