# image preview on change does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching for 2 days on "how to preview an image before upload". I see online live demo and copy past all code as it was. I rename my class name to match the additional js code. My code is:

```
    $('#edit-image-upload-wrapper').prepend('<div id="imagePreview"></div>');

     $(function() {
    $("#edit-image-upload-wrapper").bind("change", function()
    {
       // alert("it works");
        var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
        if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) alert("no file selected");//return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

        if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
            var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

            reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div

                $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I inspect my html dom and see the following code :

```
<div class="form-item" id="edit-image-upload-wrapper"><div id="imagePreview"></div>
 <label for="edit-image-upload">Upload Your Picture: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="file" name="files[image_upload]" class="form-file required" id="edit-image-upload" size="60">

 <div class="description"><p>You need to provide a passport sized image in jpg/jpeg or png format. The image size has to be 100kb or lower.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Which is exactly same as this demo: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-show-image-thumbnail-before-upload-with-jquery_573.html

But when I change the image , alert("no file selected"); works that proves no file selected.  What am I doing wrong. please help.

Comment: Why would you have two NOT checks in `var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];` ?

Answer (score -1):

Check my previews answer is work fine show image before upload

[Show an image preview before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069421/show-an-image-preview-before-upload/39223477#39223477)