# jQuery Image Preview From Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have This Input Box With `Type="text"` for choose image from  `file manager`.

HTML:

```
<input id="images" class="form-control" type="text" name="img">
```

After choose Image From file manager I have This ouput:

[image]

Now I need to create image preview from this text box and url using Html and Jquery Or Bootstrap Popover.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14069481/3132718

Comment: @user3132718: Please Note: `type="text"`

Comment: If this is a text input, how do you choose files from the file manager? How do you open it without type=file?

Comment: @user3132718 I was wondering that too...

Comment: Is it possible? Why don't you just use `type=file`? Then the linked answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you enter the image in the input, but try this.

HTML:

```
<input id="images" class="form-control" type="text" name="img">
<div class="preview">
    <img src="" class="preview-image" alt="">
</div>

<a href="http://cdn2.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/google-.jpg">Add Image</a>
```

CSS:

```
.preview-image { display: none; height: auto; width: 200px; }
```

JS:

```
$('.form-control').on('change', function(){
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    $('.preview-image').attr('src', inputVal).fadeIn();
})


$('a').on('click', function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.form-control').val(href).trigger('change');
    return false;
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zd9JL/1/)