# Preview ImageField after "Choose File" button was selected

Tags: ajax, django, preview, django-models, filefield

So I have a really basic form with an `ImageField` implemented

```
# form
class MyForm(forms.Form):       
    my_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)

# Model
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", null=True, blank=True)

# view

my_model = MyModel.objects.create(
    my_image=cd['my_image'] )
```

It's working fine, now how can I preview the image right after the user press the button "choose file"? Is there any way to accomplish this with Django or shall I use Ajax?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best done on the client-side using JavaScript. All modern browsers now can do this using HTML5 file API. There is no need to round-trip the file from the server.

[Previous StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069481/315168)

[Related Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).