# PHP file to accept user input

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Post</title>
</head>
<body>

<p> Sub-Category:  <select><option id="subCtgry"></option></select></p>
<p> Location:  <select><option id="lctn"></option></select></p>
<p> Title: <input type="text" name="ttl" size="80"></p>
<p> Price: <input type="text" name="prc" size="10"></p>
<p> Description: <textarea class="scrollabletextbox" name="prc" style="width:600pt;height:100pt;overflow:scroll"></textarea></p>
<p> Email:  <input type="text" name="email" size="80"></p>
<p> Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="cEmail" size="80"></p>
<p>I agree with terms and conditions <input type="checkbox" name="chckbx"></p>
<form>
Optional Fields:
<br>
<br>
    Image 1 (Max 5 MB): <input type="file" name="img1" size="4MB">
<br>
<br>
    Image 2 (Max 5 MB): <input type="file" name="img2">
<br>
<br>
    Image 3 (Max 5 MB): <input type="file" name="img3">
<br>
<br>
    Image 3 (Max 5 MB): <input type="file" name="img3">
<br>
<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to write a PHP file to accept user input from the New Post above. And also want to show a prewiew to user before they confirm. How can I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need show file for confirm upload, or confirm that file can be uploaded by user

Comment: for second case you'll like to use File in JS.

Comment: Messy html. form tag should be there enclosing all input type tags. Is the request get or post. Form should contain multipart form data for file type data submission. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Currently it sounds like you just want us to teach you introductory PHP.  There are many tutorials for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To upload a file:**
Set your form method to POST and and the encoding type to the form element to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) on w3schools how to handle a file upload.

**To preview the selected image:**
Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069481/6297398) on stackoverflow.

If you need help after trying the solutions/tutorials above: Let us know and explain what you have tried (relevant code snippets) and where you are stuck. We're happy to help you!

Comment: That works. Thanks again.