# How to preview image uploaded in previous page, before saving it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have Rails form that uses Active Storage to upload image. I can preview the image fine on the same page. But when user submits the form, I want to show them Preview page to confirm all info before finally submitting.

Right now, I'm only validating data before taking user to Preview page. file-input ofcourse does not allow pre-filling the data for security reasons, and the image path from Active Storage comes out broken.

So how can I show thumbnail of the uploaded image from the previous page, on the Preview page, without having to save data? Is that possible? Or do I have to do a save?

Reason I prefer not to save is it minimize spam from people just trying it out.

Tha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069421/show-an-image-preview-before-upload

Comment: Thanks @alex808 but my issue is showing the image in the next page, not the same.

Comment: in this case you must use post ajax form with client side result page and  locally saved FileReader image preview, if I understanded it right

Comment: @Alex808 Thanks. This might be the way.